# ARCHOS 80 G9 - Android 3.2 - write file to SD Card

Tags: android

I have ARCHOS 80 G9 Tablet. How can I save file to SD Card? When I try to use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

files are stored on tablet's memory. This device uses internal memory instead of SD Card. The same application is working properly on the emulator.

Comment: Hey, go and update your G9 to Ice Cream Sandwich!! Really improves performance :) That was off-topic, I know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method gets the primary external storage medium, which does not necessarily mean the SD Card. If you want the SD Card, you will have to manually specify the path